# Problem with scrollview, it scrolls more

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextfield

I have  a scrollView and i want to scroll it automatically when i select an textField
(i am filling a form here)
i am using following method to scroll it

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{   
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,50*(textField.tag-1))];
}
```

Now the problem is that i have more than 10 text fields and  when i reached to the seventh textField the scrollView scrolls  more .
I also tried to print the CGPointMake()'s values...and it is showing correct values..but the scroller goes beyond the range what is expected..
Look at following images

The following 2 images showing control on textFields  tag <7

[image]
[image]

But when control reaches to 7th textField it scrolls more

[image]

and after this it goes beyond bounds.

This problem occurs only when i move from one textFields to another without pressing that return button(i mean with `resignFirstResponder`).But when i press that return button and then go to the next field then all works fine.

Can anyone suggest where should be the problem..?

Comment: If I can suggest an alternative solution: Use a tableview for this. All that is done for you in a tableview. Just make a custom cell or use static cells and finally use scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: for your scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't scroll because it doesn't contain enough content.  It will stop when the bottom edge of the content reaches the bottom end of the frame.  Use something like

```
CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (size.width, size.height + ADDITIONAL_HEIGHT);
```

when setting up the scroll view, or in your -viewDidLoad: method, if it was loaded from a XIB.

Answer (score 1):

It should keep the text field being edited on the screen - i.e. scroll automatically - so you shouldn't need to do anything?

However, it might be trying to edit a text field that is behind the keyboard - so the better solution would be:

```
//Get notifications of the keyboard opening and closing
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //Get the keyboard height
    int h = [self.view convertRect:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] toView:nil].size.height;
    //Change the inset of the scroll view and scroll bars
    scrollView.contentInset = scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, h, 0);
}
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    scrollView.contentInset = scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.declare a variable

```
     CGPoint svos;
```

in .h file and do this.

```
       - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
svos = scr.contentOffset;//scr is my scroll view
CGPoint pt;
CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:scr];
pt = rc.origin;
pt.x = 0;
pt.y -= 60;
[scr setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];   
//NSLog(@"%f",pt.y);
     }
```